# Using sessions to create popup message after redirect wouldn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on my own forum system and I need to show popup messages after user actions, whether it's a success message or a failure message.

I've made a big research and tried many methods to get this type of a system but the method that made the most sense in my case was using sessions as the trigger and also to store the message itself.

This is what I came up with:

```
function popupMessage(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('.popup_message').remove('');
        }, 3000); 
        $('.popup_message').fadeOut();
    }, 3000);
    $('.header').append('<div class="popup_message success"><span><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check-circle"></i></span><p>success</p></div>');
}
```

This function is on my js file which holds all of my functions.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['message'])){
    $message = $_SESSION['message'];
    echo '
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/myscripts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var message = \''.$message.'\';
            popupMessage()
        </script>';
    unset($_SESSION['message']);
}
```

That piece of code is on file which is included on the header of every page on my forum.

```
$_SESSION['message'] = 'success!';
header("Location: $location");
```

And those 2 rows are beeing executed for an example when a form is submitted.

The function `popupMessage()` is working well by itself but it simply won't work when I call it through the `if(isset($_SESSION['message']))` condition.

When I've tried to replace the function call in a simple `alert()` it was working fine which means that the message is set, but the function just wouldn't run when it's called through the condition.

Comment: You need to make sure you're calling `popupMessage()` below where the HTML of the popup message is created in the DOM due to the order of operations. Otherwise, you can load it in the `$(document).ready();` function like so `$(document).ready(function() {popupMessage()});` to ensure the HTML element exists before executing JS on it.

Comment: @DanielG Wow, it was that simple. Thank you so much for the quick reply i am so happy right now, thank you very much Daniel.

Comment: You should vote up his comment if it helped you @AfikHabaz

Comment: Also @DanielG why not answer as an answer instead of as a comment? Saves others from trying to answer. Gives you more points if you get an accepted answer.

Comment: Fair enough, I posted it as an answer now too.

Comment: @geoidesic I couldn't find any way to upvote his comment before but i did now when he posted it as an answer, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure you're calling `popupMessage()` below where the HTML of the popup message is created in the DOM due to the order of operations. Otherwise, you can load it in the `$(document).ready();` function like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  popupMessage();
});
```

to ensure the HTML element exists before executing JS on it.